# Sorting chronologically in webgrind

Tags: debugging, xdebug, webgrind

I just started using Webgrind to analyze php function calls. Is there any way to sort the calls in the order they were made, rather than alphabetically by name or by the number of times a function was called?

For example, under `$PizzaBuilder->__construct`, I know that the call to `$MenuDatabase->getComboList` happens before the call to `$PizzaBuilder->selectCombo`, but there doesn't seem to be any way to get the calls to display in that order.

(The clickable column headers are Calls, which sorts alphabetically, Count, and Total Call Cost.) This would be desired in both the main Function column and the expanded Calls under each function.

([Full-size photo at Flickr](http://www.flickr.com/photos/hookedbyesther/12523531144/))

[image]